# create a new file as IResource in a project eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, rcp

This maybe simple but how can you programmaticaly create a file under a custom project in an eclipse RCP app?

I tried various ways but the file is not recognized as an eclipse resource for example if I just create a file through new fileoutput stream.

Is there an easy way to create the file as an IResource in the project?

Answer (score 3):

Examples:

```
IFile file = project.getFile(new Path("path/of/your/file"));    
IFolder folder = project.getFolder(new Path("path/of/your/folder"));
```

After that, you can create them:

```
file.create(InputStream stream, boolean force, IProgressMonitor monitor);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are used common navigator framework and the file which created by outputstream is not visible in navigator, is it? if so, i guess the reason is that you are not using platform way correspondly, so you can use the way which Timo provided. If you are implemented navigator by youself, then i guess you need to rebuild and refresh your navigator by youself too. i'm implementing a navigator by myself, so that i can create file by outputstream in myway. hold it helps. : )